# Stationarity of ARMA-like time series

Tags: st.statistics, time-series

It is well known that for $X_t \sim ARMA(p,q)$ where $\phi(B)X_t = \theta(B)Z_t, Z_t\sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$, if $\phi(z)\neq0$ in the unit circle, $\{X_t\}$ is stationary.

Now assume $\{Y_t, t=0, \pm1, ...\}$ is a stationary time series. $\phi(B)X_t = \theta(B)Y_t$. If $\phi(z)\neq0$ in the unit circle, does $\{X_t\}$ have a stationary solution?

This question is from *Brockwell* Problem 3.4. To derive (weak) stationarity, it's clear that $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ can come from one of the root of $\phi(1)x = \theta(1)\mathbb{E}Y_t$. But how can we define the acvf $\gamma_X(h)$ to let our solution of $X_t$ stationary?